# SyncAdapter and backend API; how should AccountManager / AccountAuthenticator deal with multiple login types?

Tags: android, accountmanager

#### TL;DR

Android app provides login at my backend server using a choice of either custom account (user creates a username and password) or social login (instant sign-in using Google).

What is the correct, standard way to deal with multiple authentication types within the `AccountManager`, `Account`, and `AccountAuthenticator` used by my `SyncAdapter`?

#### LONGER VERSION

### What I want to achieve

I have a REST backend server (Node.js / Loopback) for my Android application.

This backend shall allow my application's users to CRUD database objects.

Naturally, a form of account creation and login is required at the server. I wish to support both 'custom' account creation (whereby the user specifies a username and password) and a Google social login (whereby the user logs in using a selected Google account).

### What I have so far

I have built my backend server.

This backend server successfully supports both custom account creation and login (whereby the server sends back an auth token it creates) and also authentication using a Google Auth 2.0 code.

I am familiar with the use of the Google API console to create the Auth 2.0 credentials.

I have familiarised myself with the new Google Sign-in API. I have successfully used the sign-in example application (which demonstrates the new `Auth.GoogleSignInApi`, `GoogleSignInOptions`, etc.) to retrieve an auth code associated with my Google account. I can then successfully use that auth code to authenticate at my backend.

I have implemented the entire working 'skeleton' `SyncAdapter`, associated service, stub authenticator, dummy `Account`, etc.

## The question

I feel I understand the individual lower level bits and pieces and I've got them to work, but I'm struggling to work out how to piece this together and involve `Account`s and the `AccountManager`.

What is the best-practice, block-level architecture I should have to (a) use the `Auth.GoogleSignInApi` from the `SyncAdapter`, and (b) support the alternative custom account?

## How I think it may be done

If my app were to only log into my backend using Google, then I *think* the scenario should be like this:

- I create an `AccountAuthenticator` that makes use of `Auth.GoogleSignInApi` (the new sign-in API) inside of it. Specifically, `.getAuthToken()` would see if the `AccountManager` already has a Google OAuth 2.0 code. If not, it would make use of `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...)` to get an auth code from Google. Once I have that auth code, I can use it to authenticate at my server (already proven and tested).
- I already have a custom `Account` object. This appears under Settings -> Accounts & Sync as (e.g.) 'MyApp', and tapping it provides a setting to enable or disable sync. That would stay as it is. Even though I'm signing in using Google, I still need to have this custom `Account` object.

Does this sound like the right approach so far?

Now, if my app is to offer both Google and custom account creation/login, then the way I can see this working possibly is:

- During initial setup, the user has to choose Custom Account or Sign-in using Google.
- If they choose Custom Account, then perhaps I would save their credentials (in a secure way) in the `AccountManager`. Also, importantly, I would have to somehow persist (perhaps somehow within the `Account` object, or in `SharedPreferences`) that this is a custom account.
- If they choose Google sign-in, then invoke `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...)` to go through the Google account selection and authentication process. When I have the auth code, I persist it in the `AccountManager`, and I somehow persist the fact that this is a `Google` account login, not custom account.
- I still have just one custom "MyApp" `Account`.
- When my `SyncAdapter` runs, the "MyApp" `Account` is passed in, and my `AccountAuthenticator` tries to retrieve an existing auth code.
- Then, assuming existing token retrieval succeeded, the `AccountAuthenticator` has to determine whether this is a custom or Google login. If it's a custom login, then my `SyncAdapter` calls the backend's `user/login` endpoint. If it's a Google login, then my `SyncAdapter` calls my backend's `/auth/google/callback?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` with the auth code. In other words, the `AccountAuthenticator` knows it is obtaining one of several types of auth codes from the `AccountManager`. If the `AccountAuthenticator` determines it doesn't have a valid auth token, it then has to either hit my own backend API for one, *or* hit Google for an OAuth token, depending on the account type. Afterwards, given a token, the `SyncAdapter` has to know what kind of account it's for.

An alternative way I have thought of is:

- My `Account` object is only created and stored in the `AccountManager` after the point where the user has chosen the login type (manual account creation or Google login).
- The `Account` type or name string would have a tag to indicate the (sub) account type.
- The `AccountAuthenticator` would determine the account type from that tag, and obtain a fresh token either from my API or Google depending on it.
- Or... perhaps I even have *multiple* `AccountAuthenticators`; one for custom account and one for Google sign-in. Which authenticator gets called by the `AccountManager` would somehow depend on the (sub) account type. I don't actually know if this concept is possible.

---

I agree with S.D.'s excellent comment that basically states the `AccountAuthenticator` should only ever pass back one kind of token - the API's own access token (what Loopback calls the `AccessToken`). The `AccountManager` will only store that type of token.

If a fresh API accessToken is needed, the `AccountAuthenticator` should effectively hide away the details of how it's obtained. So, if the `AccountAuthenticator` knows it needs to get a new API accessToken, it has  to ether hit my API's /login endpoint with stored credentials, *or* use `Auth.GoogleSignInApi` *together with* my API's /auth/google endpoint, in order to get the accessToken.

Expanding on that further, if my API's accessTokens had a sliding TTL, perhaps it's feasible that doing the whole Google OAuth procedure is only ever needed once, or very infrequently.

Comment: Base your server authentication on one auth token type: server's own generated auth token. All social logins/registers can be converted to this token that uniquely identifies the user on server. Now you have one account type: your app's account, with one token to save on device: server generated.

Comment: Thank you @S.D. I like the sound of that. So, this means `AccountManager` only stores the `accessToken` (the API's own auth token), *never* an OAuth code. This means that once the `AccountManager` provides the code to the `SyncAdapter`, the `SyncAdapter` can start hitting REST endpoints straight away using that `accessToken`. This makes total sense. However, would I be correct that if a new accessToken is needed, the `AccountAuthenticator` would still need to 'switch' on the account type, and either hit my server's /api/login or /auth/google accordingly?